# Autocad.net Save complex Object

Tags: serialization, autocad, autocad-plugin

I'm working on a project in AutoCAD using c#, my application data is stored in complex objects
(String, double, objectId, arrays, list...) and I would like to save data for later using (serialize or saved in AutoCAD drawing) and if I re-open AutoCAD and reload my project, I can find all data in my object

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So You need to use XData.

Details and sample You can find here:
https://www.keanw.com/2007/04/adding_xdata_to.html

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize your class into a binary stream and then you can save it in the drawing as a bunch of binary chunks (see [this topic](https://your%20class%20into%20a%20binary%20stream%20and%20then%20you%20can%20save%20it%20in%20the%20drawing%20as%20a%20bunch%20of%20binary%20chunks))

But most of the time you should directly store data in Xrecords of a DBDictionary.

```
public abstract class RecordableObject
{
    protected ObjectId dictionaryId;
    protected Database database;

    public string Key { get; }

    protected RecordableObject(string key, Database db = null)
    {
        database = db ?? HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
        Key = key;
        using (var tr = database.TransactionManager.StartOpenCloseTransaction())
        {
            var NOD = (DBDictionary)tr.GetObject(database.NamedObjectsDictionaryId, OpenMode.ForRead);
            DBDictionary dictionary;
            if (NOD.Contains(Key))
            {
                dictionaryId = NOD.GetAt(Key);
            }
            else
            {
                NOD.UpgradeOpen();
                dictionary = new DBDictionary();
                dictionaryId = NOD.SetAt(Key, dictionary);
                tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(dictionary, true);
            }
            tr.Commit();
        }
    }

    public abstract void SavePropertiesToDictionary();
    public abstract void SetPropertiesFromDictionary();

    protected void SaveData(string key, params TypedValue[] values)
    {
        using (var tr = database.TransactionManager.StartOpenCloseTransaction())
        {
            var dictionary = (DBDictionary)tr.GetObject(dictionaryId, OpenMode.ForRead);
            Xrecord xrecord;
            if (dictionary.Contains(key))
            {
                xrecord = (Xrecord)tr.GetObject(dictionary.GetAt(key), OpenMode.ForWrite);
            }
            else
            {
                xrecord = new Xrecord();
                dictionary.UpgradeOpen();
                dictionary.SetAt(key, xrecord);
                tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(xrecord, true);
            }
            xrecord.Data = new ResultBuffer(values);
            tr.Commit();
        }
    }

    protected T GetData<T>(string key)
    {
        using (var tr = database.TransactionManager.StartOpenCloseTransaction())
        {
            var dictionary = (DBDictionary)tr.GetObject(dictionaryId, OpenMode.ForRead);
            if (dictionary.Contains(key))
            {
                var xrecord = (Xrecord)tr.GetObject(dictionary.GetAt(key), OpenMode.ForRead);
                if (xrecord.Data != null)
                    return (T)xrecord.Data.AsArray()[0].Value;
            }
            return default;
        }
    }

    protected T[] GetDataArray<T>(string key)
    {
        using(var tr = database.TransactionManager.StartOpenCloseTransaction())
        {
            var dictionary = (DBDictionary)tr.GetObject(dictionaryId, OpenMode.ForRead);
            if (dictionary.Contains(key))
            {
                var xrecord = (Xrecord)tr.GetObject(dictionary.GetAt(key), OpenMode.ForRead);
                if (xrecord.Data != null)
                    return xrecord.Data.AsArray().Select(tv => (T)tv.Value).ToArray();
            }
            return default;
        }
    }
}
```

Derived class example:

```
public class RecordableExample : RecordableObject
{
    public double Size { get; set; }
    public ObjectId ObjectId { get; set; }
    public int[] Ints { get; set; }

    public RecordableExample(string key, Database db = null) : base(key, db) { }

    public override void SavePropertiesToDictionary()
    {
        SaveData(nameof(Size), new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.Real, Size));
        SaveData(nameof(ObjectId), new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.Handle, ObjectId.Handle));
        if (Ints != null)
            SaveData(nameof(Ints), Ints.Select(i => new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.Int32, i)).ToArray());
    }

    public override void SetPropertiesFromDictionary()
    {
        Size = GetData<double>(nameof(Size));
        Ints = GetDataArray<int>(nameof(Ints));
        var handle = new Handle(Convert.ToInt64(GetData<string>(nameof(ObjectId))));
        if (database.TryGetObjectId(handle, out var id)) 
            ObjectId = id;
    }
}
```